# How to handle a function that is called too many times before the first call is terminated in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I have a function that plots some  data into a chart by using some SVG elements. The chart is a virtual chart because just a small portion of the data are plotted at any given time.

The function is called when the user scroll the chart ('touchmove') and a new portion of the data is built and then displayed.

The problems arises when the user scroll too fast and the function can not  keep up with the new requests because it is called to many times.

How can I force the function to drop the work it is doing in order to start it again with fresh new data?

When a function is called many times, before the first call has been terminated, do those calls are staked somewhere? Is it possible to delete some of them before they are executed when they are not required any more?

Answer (score 1):

Use the debounce function http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Note: it is already included in underscore or lodash.